# Tkinter couldn't load an image after window change

Tags: python, image, tkinter

I am struggling with this Tkinter and I read all the topics related to my problem.

And the problem is that I have Login/Register page and after successful authentication, I want to hide the login window and then show the MainWindow. Here I think is my mistake - how I open the new window.

I'll give you some code to explain:

This is my login function. `form_instance` is the Login/Register form that is passed from another file/script.

```
def handle_login(self, email, password, form_instance):
        auth = self.firebase.auth()
        user = auth.sign_in_with_email_and_password(email, password)

        form_instance.destroy()

        _app = FutBot()
```

This is the code that loads the image:

```
        image = Image.open('./img/fut_bot_bg2.png')
        background_image = ImageTk.PhotoImage(image)
        background_label = ttk.Label(self.window, image=background_image)
        background_label.photo = background_image
        background_label.place(x=0, y=0, relwidth=1, relheight=1)
```

The exception:

```
Exception in Tkinter callback
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\PC\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 1885, in __call__
    return self.func(*args)
  File "D:\Projects\FutSnipeBot\Auth\auth_form.py", line 52, in handle_login
    auth_handler.handle_login(email=self.email_input_field.get(), password=self.password_input_field.get(),
  File "D:\Projects\FutSnipeBot\sign_log_pyre.py", line 59, in handle_login
    _app = FutBot()
  File "D:\Projects\FutSnipeBot\fut_bot.py", line 24, in __init__
    self.configure_bot_gui()
  File "D:\Projects\FutSnipeBot\fut_bot.py", line 41, in configure_bot_gui
    image = Image.open('./img/fut_bot_bg2.png')
  File "C:\Users\PC\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python39\site-packages\PIL\Image.py", line 2891, in open
    fp = builtins.open(filename, "rb")
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: './img/fut_bot_bg2.png'
```

Here you go the code:

1. The main entry file (Login form): pastebin.com/i7cCssR7
2. The middle file which handles the authentication and opens the MainWindow: pastebin.com/58Lvra0L
3. The MainWindow(I removed the functionality as it is not related to the problem): pastebin.com/4YMY4dSV

Hope this will do the work

And before you say something I want to mention that if I run the MainWindow the image loads without a problem.

The MainWindow is a class implementation. The function that handles login is also class implementation. If you need more code or information mention what you want.

I hope someone would help me as I am a beginner with python and it seems enjoyable to work with this language.

Comment: If python says it can’t find a file it is telling the truth: that file doesn’t exist in the current working directory.

Comment: Okay, then explain how the image loads if I run only MainWindow, without the transition from Login to MainWindow? Here is the key - this transition is wrong in my opinion, but unfortunately I don't know what is wrong.

Comment: The path is relative to where the py file is located

Comment: Without seeing a proper [mcve] we can only speculate. Maybe some code somewhere changes the working directory.

Comment: @CoolCloud: no, that is incorrect. It is relative to the current working directory which may or may not be where the file is located.

Comment: @BryanOakley You mean the path from where python is being run from?

Comment: Here you go the code:
1) The main entry file (Login form): https://pastebin.com/i7cCssR7
2) The middle file which handles the authentication and opens the MainWindow: https://pastebin.com/58Lvra0L
3) The MainWindow(I removed the functionality as it is not related to the problem): https://pastebin.com/4YMY4dSV

Hope this will do the work

Comment: The image path in the first link is `../img/fut_bot_bg2.png`, while that in the third link is `./img/fut_bot_bg2.png`.  They are different.

Comment: @acw1668 Yes, the file in the first link is in a folder named Auth, but the file in the third link is in the root folder, so the first file needs to go 1 back to access the 'img' folder while the third is at the same level as the folder. Can someone pay attention to the way I switch between Login and MainWindow. I think and I am almost sure that the problem is there, but I don't know how to fix it. I tried many approaches but any of them doesn't work.

Comment: @CoolCloud: see http://www.linfo.org/current_directory.html or just do a search in the internet for _current working directory_.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this out:

```
image = Image.open(r'.\img\fut_bot_bg2.png')
```

Comment: glad it did. im a newbie to python lol. I cant find a solution to a problem and i just saw this. My 13 year old brain cant handle all this

Comment: I am a newbie to python too, but here there is a solution for literally everything.